# Masonite - AttributeError > 'str' object has no attribute 'filename'

Tags: python, frameworks, masonite

I have a form that looks like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="/posts">
    {{ csrf_field }}
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="file" name="image">

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

But when I submit this form and try to upload I am only getting the name of the image:

```
def posts(self, request: Request, upload: Upload):
    upload.store(request().input('image'))
```

I get hit with an exception:

`AttributeError > 'str' object has no attribute 'filename'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is thrown because you do not have an encoding set on your HTML form here:

```
<form method="POST" action="/posts">
```

This should be changed to:

```
<form method="POST" action="/posts" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

This will encode the image so Masonite can read it as an object and not a string.